# How to fill an empty list with values from user input?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Okay, so I am at ground level in python, currently trying to do the following:
I want to create a list of numbers received from user input, so for example I have an empty list and when prompted I type 4 and script returns me a list containing 4 items like 0, 1, 2, 3, if i type in 8 it will return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and so on.

So far, after numerous attempts I came up with the following code:

```py
x = input("Please enter a number: ")

numbers = []
for i in range(int(x)):
    numbers.append(i)
    print(numbers)
```

It kinda works, but not really, it doesn't do exactly what I wanted:

```py
Please enter a number: 4
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And I want it to return this :

```py
Please enter a number: 4

[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Given my current proficiency in python I have no clue how to work around it.
Many thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Try and print at the end of the script rather than as the loop is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the `print` function out of the loop:

```
x = input("Please enter a number: ")

numbers = []
for i in range(int(x)):
    numbers.append(i)

print(numbers)
```

Comment: LOL, I didn't expect that to be this easy. Cant really uderstand WHY it works this way, but it does, thanks :D

Comment: @Ejdzbikej in your version you print the list in every iteration while you're still adding numbers to the list. With moving the print function out of the loop you're just waiting to print the list until all the numbers have been added.

Comment: @Ejdzbikej It works because, in Python, all statements to be processed under a loop, as here, or a conditional like `if...` are indented. That's how Python knows what to process in the loop. By unindenting the `print(numbers)`, python doesn't process it in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

```py
list=[]
num=int(input("Enter the number you wanna insert:")

for i in range(num):
    x=int(input("Enter Number:")
    list.append(x)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)